# netrw freezes for seconds when entering window for a folder on network drive with many zip files

Tags: netrw

I have split windows on Vim/Gvim, one of which is opened to a folder rather than an text file.  When the folder is on a network drive, Vim/Gvim freezes for 5-10 seconds whenever I change focus to that window.  The task manager shows Gvim taking up the most bandwidth (0.8 Mbps) during that time.

Is Vim unpacking all the zip files in the folder that is being viewed?

I see some delay when enter folders with many subfolders, but only a second or so.

Is there any way to avoid the delay when the folder contains many zip files?

Comment: Network drive means it is probably refreshing when it gets focus. If that folder is also a zip, then yes, there is a network transfer and an unzip (but should  only be for the filenames, not the full content)

Comment: It's not bad at all the window is viewing the list of files within a zip file.  It's debilitating when I'm viewing an actual directory containing many zip files.  I'm wondering if netrw goes through each zip file to assemble a listing of its contents so that it is "prepared" to rapidly show it to the user if he/she decides to descend into a zip file.

Comment: hm could be. You could try running with debug or verbose (-V) to find out, or take a look at the netrw code (be warned, it’s a behemoth)

Comment: Odd. After reading `:help netrw-debug`, I fetched `Decho.vba` and copied the system-wide `autoload/netwrw*` files into `~/.vim` in preparation to use it.  However, the delay doesn't seem to be manifesting today.  Thanks for the tip anyway.  I have it on hand for when the problem resurfaces.